# How to find a rendered file in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, filepath

i got the job to edit a page. And now i can see the rendered and displayed page, but i can´t find the template to work on it.

The controller which is rendering the page:

```
return $this->render('FEBundle:Public\Impressum:Impressum.html.twig',array());
```

So how do i get the path from a rendered file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Referencing Templates in a Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html)

[Referencing Templates in a Bundle - overriding-bundle-templates](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html)

templates should be in:

```
app/Resources/FEBundle/views/Public/Impressum/Impressum.html.twig
```

or in:

```
FEBundle/Resources/views/Public/Impressum/Impressum.html.twig
```

EDIT:

if you want server path from controller:

```
    $parser = $this->container->get('templating.name_parser');
    $locator = $this->container->get('templating.locator');

    $path = $locator->locate($parser->parse('FEBundle:Public\Impressum:Impressum.html.twig'));
```

Comment: i thought more if it would be possible through a method

Answer (score 1):

Probably in `FEBundle/Resources/views/Public/Impressum/Impressum.html.twig`

Comment: ok it is there^^ netbeans didn´t show me all folders......
but question stays. is there a way to get the path?

Comment: Arf :) Anyway, glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Symfony 2.7, you can use the Twig profiler: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-twig-profiler